# Limit/Reduce number of Core in App Engine Flex Instance

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm hosting my back end project on Google Cloud (App Engine Flex Instance), for now I have only 10 users but they charge me 250$ per month now, because I use several core, and so I used 2400 hours of accumulated instance time. Insane for only 10 users and not so much traffic!
Can I reduce or limit the number of core used by my back end?

Comment: So why do you use so many cores for only 10 users? What is/are your `.yaml` file(s), or at least their scaling sections?

Comment: shoutout to @DanCornilescu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing#flexible-environment-instances), the price for App Engine Flexible is computed as vCPU per core hour of usage. Basically, it does not matter if users reach your back-end project. It matters only if many users reach your App Engine Flexible deployment, increasing the number of resources required to serve them, thus increasing the price.

Yes, you can reduce the number of cores used in the back end, through the [resource settings](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#resource-settings) of your `app.yaml` configuration file. You might also want to check [service scaling settings](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#services), to control the way App Engine Flexible assigns more resources based on your service's demands.

Comment: Thanks it's exactly what I was looking for... The automatic scaling values was not set, so by default it used too much resources. My expensive mistake! :-(